# How to initialiaze an object and assign different variables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have created an object where i need to assign some variables(parameters) and when the object is called, the variables(parameters) change. Here is my code:

```
var Modal = {

    init: function () {

        contact1: "";
        contact2: "";
        aboutus1: "";
        aboutus2: "";
        privacy1: "";
        privacy2: "";
        terms1:   "";
        terms2:   "";

        $(".modaltrigger").removeAttr("target");

        $(".modaltrigger").click(function () {

            if ($(this).is("#contact")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', contact1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', contact2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#aboutus")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', aboutus1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', aboutus2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#termsconditions")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', terms1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', terms2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#privacy")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', privacy1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', privacy2);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I am trying to initialize the object above, and it does not work:

```
    Modal.init(

        contact1: "http:www.test1.com";
        contact2: "http:www.test2.com";
        aboutus1: "http:www.test3.com";
        aboutus2: "http:www.test4.com";
        privacy1: "http:www.test5.com";
        privacy2: "http:www.test6.com";
        terms1:   "http:www.test7.com";
        terms2:   "http:www.test8.com"

    );
```

Comment: You have many syntactic problems. The console should point them.

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial about functions and objects: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html, http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html. Also have a look at the MDN documentation regarding object literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers. Basically if you want to pass arguments to a function, define it with `function foo(a, b) {...}` and pass the arguments as comma separated list: `foo('bar', 42);`.

Comment: To declare a variable in a block, use `var a=value;`, not `a:value;`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntactic problems. A tutorial and some documentations about variable declarations should be consulted instead of SO.

Comment: I noted my syntax problems and changes the : to "="

Comment: I hate constructors with 5+ arguments. Instead you can create setters and if you want to save few key-strokes you can chain them. For example: [without chaining](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7J7/) and [with chaining](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7J7/1/).

Comment: still it does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is Done like this way,

i Guess this is what you want to do.

```
var Modal = {

    init: function (args) {

              //then access your values like this
            contact1=   args.contact1;
            contact2 = args.contact2;
            ..........
            .........
            .........
         }
}
```

And to initiate this method you have write as

```
Modal.init({
contact1:"contact str",
contact2:"contact str",
.....
.....
lastitem : "last str"
});
```

Comment: Yes this one works! Well it was mainly syntax errors, thanks dude ;)