# Javascript Object Passing Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have written an object and it is working fine, except am not happy with it as i think it can be improved:

Here it is:

```
var Modal = {

    init: function (contact1,contact2,aboutus1,aboutus2,terms1,terms2,privacy1,privacy2) {

        $(".modaltrigger").removeAttr("target");

        $(".modaltrigger").click(function () {

            if ($(this).is("#contact")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', contact1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', contact2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#aboutus")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', aboutus1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', aboutus2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#termsconditions")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', terms1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', terms2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#privacy")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', privacy1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', privacy2);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I am calling the method above as:

```
Modal.init("test.com","test2.com","test3.com", "test4.com","test5.com", "test6.com","test7.com","test8.com");
```

The above is working fine, but what about if i have long string values to pass? Is there any way, i can declare a variable as parameter , and when calling the method , i assign the variables dynamically? How do i write that code..

I was thinking of calling the method as:

```
Modal.init({
 var 1: "firstsrting",
 var 2: "secondsting",
 ...
 ...
});
```

Please help..

Comment: Didn't the accepted answer to your last question exactly answer this ?

Comment: it did not work as expected as everything that was declared inside the method is overriding the values that i set when calling the method :(

Comment: @Wasiim: Look at [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18119567/157247) again. It shows you **exactly** how to do this.

Comment: Modal.init({
contact1:"contact str",
contact2:"contact str",
.....
.....
lastitem : "last str"
});

Comment: the above variables is not set when the method is called

Comment: possibly it has not been properly set in: var Modal = {

    init: function (args) {

              //then access your values like this
            contact1=   args.contact1;
            contact2 = args.contact2;
            ..........
            .........
            .........
         }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use object as one parameter.

```
var Modal = {

    init: function (params) {

        $(".modaltrigger").removeAttr("target");

        $(".modaltrigger").click(function () {

            if ($(this).is("#contact")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', params.contact1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', params.contact2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#aboutus")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', params.aboutus1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', params.aboutus2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#termsconditions")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', params.terms1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', params.terms2);

            } else if ($(this).is("#privacy")) {

                $('#primary_url').attr('href', params.privacy1);
                $('#secondary_url').attr('href', params.privacy2);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and call that function (method) using:

```
Modal.init({
    contact1: "http://test1.com",
    contact2: "http://test2.com",
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: Great..this works..But i can see myself repeating some codes like: inside the else if - i am pretty much doing the same thing(same function, only the parameters are changing). Can this be further improved?

Comment: @Wasiim You can shrink the code if you set id to be the same as name in `param.<name><number>` so when the id is privacy the params will be privacy1 and privacy2. So you can use `var name = $(this).attr('id'); $('#primary_url').attr('href' params[name+'1']); $('#secondary_url').attr('href', params[name+'2']);` without if.